# How do I make Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express executable files independent of c++

Tags: visual-c++

Whenever I try to build a windows executable file in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and use the created program, Microsoft Visual C++ always boots up, I want to create an executable file, just like any other windows program without having to go through Microsoft Visual C++. Any information on this would be GREATLY appreciated, Thank You

Comment: What exactly are you doing?

Comment: I am trying to create window 7 applications using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express which are independent of c++, I have been trying to solve this issue first though

Comment: That shouldn't happen at all.  What exactly are you clicking on?

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out looking for an answer to this problem on the internet without success and getting redirected to other off-topic subjects

Comment: Beening clicking on debug then on build, from the little I've read, you've got to put the created exe and code files into one folder to make an independent program, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that

Comment: And which files to move to what folder

Answer (score 0):

When you have build you program you have to copy the executable to the destination PC. When your C++ program is in the file `hello.cpp` compiled in the project `moin.vcproj` yoi have to copy the `moin.exe` to the target. There you start the `moin.exe`. The executable can be placed in any folder.

The C++ compiled program requires that the C++ run-time library is installed. Very often it's already there. But you have problems to run the executable you need to install the correct redistributable package.

Depending on the target CPU you used you need the [x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328) or the [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) distributable:

*Edit*: If you don't want to deploy your program you just use the Windows Explorer, browse to the folder where Visual Studio has created the moin.exe, and double start it with a double click. The right mouse key can offer you more possibilities like creating a shorcut.

The search function of the Explorer might help here. If you didn't change the output directory you will find the .exe somehwere below the place where your .vcproj is located.

Comment: First off I'm only using one computer to both use and create my executable files, so I still don't know which folder I'm supposed to copy the main.exe (I assumed that's what you meant) to the hello.cpp folder location, (I am not calling my cpp files "hello.cpp", but I assumed that you are using this for demo purposes) as I cannot find either of these files